# Why is this xslt copy-of example not returning expected result

Tags: xml, xslt

Using latest SaxonHE.

[This 'copy-of' example](https://www.xmltutorial.info/xslt/xslcopy-of/) isn't returning the defined result, What I'm getting is shown at the bottom of the page. What is the fix?

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<library>
    <category name="dogs">
        <book>
            <name>All about dogs</name>
            <author>Someone</author>
            <isin>true</isin>
            <daysuntilreturn>0</daysuntilreturn>
        </book>
    </category>
     <category name="cats">
        <book>
            <name>All about cats</name>
            <author>Someone</author>
            <isin>false</isin>
            <daysuntilreturn>3</daysuntilreturn>
        </book>
    </category>
</library>
```

XSL

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <myoutput>
            <xsl:copy-of select="/*/category[@name=cats]" />
        </myoutput>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Defined outout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<myoutput>
     <category name="cats">
        <book>
            <name>All about cats</name>
            <author>Someone</author>
            <isin>false</isin>
            <daysuntilreturn>3</daysuntilreturn>
        </book>
    </category>
</myoutput>
```

My output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><myoutput/>
```

Comment: You've missed out apostrophes. It should be `<xsl:copy-of select="/*/category[@name='cats']" />`, otherwise it is looking for an element named "cats" rather than a string literal.

Comment: @TimC that should be an answer not a comment...

Comment: Added it as an answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you (or rather the xml tutorial website!) have missed out apostrophes in the condition. It should be this...

```
<xsl:copy-of select="/*/category[@name='cats']" />
```

Without apostrophes like this, it will be looking for an element named "cats" in the XML, which does not exist. Adding apostrophes makes it a string literal, so it will be literally looking for the word "cats".

Answer (score 0):

Please use

```
<xsl:copy-of select="/*/category[@name='cats']" />
```

You have missed the apostrophes around the attribute name.

Comment: *I* didn't miss it.

Comment: <xsl:copy-of select="/*/category[@name=cats]" /> plse camplare it. you have missed apostrophes from  'cats',